# how to identify a selected object in tilelist?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, tilelist

**I have tilelist, which is dynamically loaded XML file with pictures,
How do I do that would be when you click on a picture in the Label gave her name?**

```
 <mx:TileList id="tileList"
             alternatingItemColors="[#FFFFFF,#EEEEEE]"
             dataProvider="{xmlListColl}"
             itemRenderer="TileListItemRenderer"
             columnCount="3"
             columnWidth="100"
             rowCount="2"
             rowHeight="100"
             direction="horizontal"
             verticalScrollPolicy="on"/>
```

Comment: Can you please try to reword it in better english?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your TileList call a function with

```
itemClick="somthingSelected();"

public function somthingSelected():void{
  trace( this.tileList.selectedItem.@id )
}
```

**"id"** is the attribute in your xml dataprovider or whatever you want it to be

Comment: public function SomthingSelected ():void {
 txt.text = this.tileList.selectedItem.title; 
   }

Comment: '<mx:TileList id="tileList"
     dataProvider="{contactsService.lastResult.title}"
                 columnCount="4"
     columnWidth="125"
     rowCount="2"
     rowHeight="100"
     verticalScrollPolicy="on" 
     itemClick="SomthingSelected ()"/>'

Comment: Also post your TileListItemRenderer